# K&R Programming in C: EX 3.3

Tags: c, gcc, kernighan-and-ritchie

EX 3.3: Write a function `expand(s1,s2)` that expands shorthand notations like a-z in the string s1 into the equivalent complete list `abc...xyz in s2`  Allow for letters of either case and digits, and be prepared to handle cases like `a-b-c` and `a-z0-9` and `-a-z`. Arrange that a leading or trailing - is taken literally.

I'm trying to solve exercise 3.3 in K&R and this is what I have:

```
void expand(char s1[], char s2[]){
    int i; // index for first string
    int j; // index for 2nd string

    for(i = 0, j = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++j){
        if(isalnum(s1[i]) && s1[i+1] == '-'){
            char c = s1[i];
            for(char c = s1[i]; c <= s1[i+2]; ++c, ++j){
                s2[j] = c;
            }
            ++i;
        } else{
            s2[j] = s1[i];
        }
    }
    s2[j] = '\0';
}
```

It succesfully expands any range, as long as it is not after any other range, ie. it doesn't add anything to s2 after the first range is finished. If I put this statement:

```
printf("%c\n", c);
```

in the second for loop, it prints out the right characters, but it doesn't add it to s2.

Sample inputs & outputs:

```
In: akls aldio a-h 19 aodk                                                 
Out: akls aldio abcdefgh

In: 0-6 a-c lol                                                              
Out: 0123456

In: a-c-g 1okd 2-4                                                           
Out: abc
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction to fix my mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I don't know if this solves it, but I would remove the `++j` from both of the `for` loops, and place them right after the places where you have written into `s2[j]`, or better, use `s2[j++]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane That worked! Any ideas why?

Comment: @PaulR Thank you. I will look into debuggers for c. I have used the one built into netbeans before, but haven't done so for c.

Comment: As the answer said. My suggestion was to increment the index *at the point of use* not elsewhere to make you grapple with the logic. @dbush also mentioned the `i+=2` before I got to it. You must skip 2 characters, not one (the third is dealt with in the `for` loop.

Comment: The i+=2 won't work for cases like `a-h-k`. I realize another modeification needs to be made, but that was something that I put in the backseat, since this problem was more pressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, suggested by dbush, you need to do one `j--`, but for cases like `a-c-g` to work you need to change your inner `for` condition too. Instead of checking `c <= s1[i+2]`, you need to check only till `c < s1[i+2]`

```
void expand(char s1[], char s2[]){
    int i; // index for first string
    int j; // index for 2nd string

    for(i = 0, j = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++j){
            if(isalnum(s1[i]) && s1[i+1] == '-'){
                    char c = s1[i];
                    /* Do it c < instead of c<= */
                    for(char c = s1[i]; c < s1[i+2]; ++c, ++j){
                            s2[j] = c;
                    }
                    --j;  /* Decrement j once */
                    ++i; 
            } else {
                    s2[j] = s1[i];
            }
    }
    s2[j] = '\0';
}
```

P.S: This code solves OP's immediate issues at hand (i.e the inputs that was shown in the original post). But, this code fails for inputs like `a-b-c-`. Also additional code is needed for inputs like `abc-DEF`, `abc--def`, `abc-456`, etc. However, as seen in comments (of this answer) OP wants to solve those issues himself.

Comment: Thank you. I realized and made this change after @dbush's answer didn't work for those cases.

Comment: There is one more issue, with this code however, try input `a-g-`, this wont work ... I am trying to fix it, I had tried only your test inputs before I posted the answer

Comment: Don't bother. It's my problem. I'm still not entirely done. I came here after I realized that I was stuck. 
Also, in your answer, you say `c < s1[i+1]` but I think you mean `c < s1[1+2]`.

Comment: yes i meant  `c < s1[i+2]`, as could be seen in the code .

Comment: This problem is nice one. I can suggest you some good inputs here. Some of them are 'abc-Def', 'abc-456', 'abc--def' apart from usual ones... The code above fails .. Hope you will fix them, and in case you need any pointers you can msg back here ....

Answer (score 3):

After your inner `for` loop, `j` is one past where it should be, so you skip writing to one position.  If that position happens to contain the value 0, it terminates the string and you don't see anything after it.

Also, `i` is one before where it should be.

Replace this:

```
        for(char c = s1[i]; c <= s1[i+2]; ++c, ++j){
            s2[j] = c;
        }
        ++i;
```

With this:

```
        for(char c = s1[i]; c <= s1[i+2]; ++c, ++j){
            s2[j] = c;
        }
        i+=2;
        j--;
```

Comment: The i needs to only increment by one, so that cases like `a-b-c` work. The rest is correct. It works, and I understand why it's not working. If you remove that part, I will mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

As sps and dbush already made it work, let me add my two cent, too.

You should keep your stuff simple and readable if possible. For example: you load too much into your loops, its not the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/). Increment/decrement only the index you defined in the first part of the for-loop. That would be the variables `i` and `c` in your case. The iterations over the vectors `s1` and `s2` should be done as close as possible to the vectors.

That gives:

```
void expand(char s1[], char s2[]){
    int i;
    int j;
    char c;
    for(i = 0, j = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(isalnum(s1[i]) && s1[i+1] == '-'){
            for(c = s1[i]; c < s1[i+2]; c++){
                s2[j++] = c;
            }
            i++;
        } else{
            s2[j++] = s1[i];
        }
    }
    s2[j] = '\0';
}
```

Doing it that way gets rid of the otherwise necessary correction `j--`

Test it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char s[200];
  char s2[200];
  int i;
  memset(s,0,200);
  memset(s2,0,200);
  // put some spaces in between the arguments
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
    // counting ommitted!
    strcat(s2,argv[i]);
    s2[strlen(s2)] = ' ';
  }
  printf("In:  %s\n",s2);
  expand(s2,s);
  printf("Out: %s\n",s);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

$ gcc -W -Wall -std=c11  expand.c -o expand
./expand 0-9 ASD a-z QWE a-ch-r
In:  0-9 ASD a-z QWE a-c-r 
Out: 0123456789 ASD abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz QWE abchijklmnopqr
```

Oh, and the `++i` et al. in the third part of the for loops: we have 2016 now.